# SQL Server CMDEXEC - Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, cmd, sql-job

I'm having an issue related using CMDEXEC in one jobstep.
Let me give you the background;

I have a console app which tries to copy backup to another location. When I run it from cmd console, it works fine. If I put it into SQL Job, it fails and gives "Access is denied" error. I need to put it to the SQL Job, windows task is not an option.

I know that the problem is that SQLSERVERAGENT service account does not have read right for the given path.

Is there any simple way other than enabling xp_cmdshell or setting proxy account? Can I give SQLSERVERAGENT account the necessary permissions without using above methods? Or Can I run cmd with admin privilege?

Answer (score 0):

OZ,

By the sounds of thing you simply need to grant read rights to the SQL Server Agent Service account on the folder structures where the backups are currently located and write rights to the destination folder.

If this is on a domain and the destination is somewhere other than the localhost the SQL Server Agent Service Account will need to be operated under a domain account and the domain rights assigned or the computer account will need to be granted the rights to the destination folder (which I wouldn't suggest as a security principle).